# output of capacitor-coupled attenuator circuit

Tags: diodes, attenuator

This is the capacitor-coupled attenuator circuit to attenuate the ac signal. I tried to get the

In DC analysis I get that $$r_{d1}=V_T/I_2, r_{d2}=V_T/I_2$$
In AC analysis,
I calculated that the gain of the circuit is $$V_o/V_i=I_1/(V_T/R+I_2)$$ by using DC analysis and AC analysis

But the simulation result doesn't work like my assumption. Is my calculation correct?

[image]

Comment: What’s the purpose of I2?

Comment: what's the purpose of the offset of V1 if it's AC-coupled anyways?

Comment: V1 is kind of input signal of the circuit. Voff is bias voltage and amplitude is the signal i want to attenuate.

Comment: I think that I1 and I2 are the variable to regulate the output voltage

Comment: which output voltage?

Comment: the place where marker is

Comment: 1 A DC or 5 A DC are not "practical" for 1N914 diodes ...

Comment: then what value would be practical? would you explain more?